# gitignore functioning differently between git 2.7 and 2.8?

Tags: git, gitignore

So I'm trying to ignore everything except for files under the **/app/code/core/Mage/** directory.

For some reason, it works on Windows (git version 2.7.0.windows), but not in my Centos machine (git version 2.8.1) - which thinks no changes has been made

git status output on Windows:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        app/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

git status output on Centos:

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)
```

my .gitignore file:

```
/**
!/app/code/core/Mage/**
```

Comment: Check filename case. Probably it's `mage`, not `Mage`

Comment: @AlexeyTen Uh, nope.

Answer (score 0):

With Git 2.18 at least, that would not work:

```
/**
!/app/code/core/Mage/**
```

The first line ignores files *and folders*. And once a folder is ignored, Git won't look into its content to exclude subfolder or subfiles.

You need to exclude the folders first, before being able to exclude files:

```
/**
!/**/
!/app/code/core/Mage/**
```

And that would work both on Windows and CentOS.